# How to format String for printing new line in PDF- not printing new line correctly- Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf

I have an output textView which I am successfully printing one calculation per new line. I expect and intend on the same occurring when I convert to PDF or print. However when I enter the string value into the PDF creation method and click the button to generate PDF from textView the pdf is all squished into a paragraph instead of one single column with new lines per calculation.

So far I've tried a few different ways of string interpolation, and many different combinations of altering the setContent method as well as altering the exportText value with no success or change...

I am using this dependancy for the PDF writing: https://github.com/RakeshPonna/PdfFileGenerator

My code for the button press:

```
// Print version button
    printableVersion.setOnClickListener {
        val exportText = testOutput.text.toString()
        val exportFilename = ""

        CreatePdf(this)
            .setPdfName("Coursing output")
            .openPrintDialog(true)
            .setContentBaseUrl(null)
            .setPageSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
            .setContent(exportText)
            .setFilePath(pdfFilePath = exportFilename)
            .setCallbackListener(object : CreatePdf.PdfCallbackListener {
                override fun onFailure(errorMsg: String) {
                    makeText(this@MetricEvenGauge, errorMsg, LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                override fun onSuccess(filePath: String) {
                    makeText(this@MetricEvenGauge, "Pdf Saved at: $filePath", LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            })
            .create()
    }
```

My textView in app:

[image]

The PDF/print screen:

[image]

Appreciate anyone's input and help :)

EDIT: After some input the problem has evolved into how to make this line break statement from the method:

```
for (index in 1..testNumber.toInt()) {
        calculation += "\nTest #$index = ${index * (testLevel + 
attempt)}"
```

Work with html, this don't work:

```
// Print version button- working of PDF printing
    printableVersion.setOnClickListener {
        val exportText = testOutput.text.toString()

        val htmlText = "<html><br>$exportText<br></html>"

        val exportFilename = ""

        CreatePdf(this)
            .setPdfName("Coursing output")
            .openPrintDialog(true)
            .setContentBaseUrl(null)
            .setPageSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
            .setContent(htmlText)
            .setFilePath(pdfFilePath = exportFilename)
            .setCallbackListener(object : 
CreatePdf.PdfCallbackListener {
                override fun onFailure(errorMsg: String) {
                    makeText(this@MetricEvenGauge, errorMsg, 
LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                override fun onSuccess(filePath: String) {
                    makeText(
                        this@MetricEvenGauge,
                        "Pdf Saved at: $filePath",
                        LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            })
            .create()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The library you're using simply loads the input into a WebView, so it would take HTML formatting. Use `<br>` for line breaks.

Comment: Could I get some help implementing that. looking at HTML makes my mind creak.

Comment: I can't find anything simple enough that I can understand to implement this. I haven't a clue how to turn my string into HTML and then format it. I don't necessarily expect a direct answer but I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction with simple documentation. I've only been at kotlin 3 weeks... I also don't understand how an HTML line break will translate this to what i want:     for (index in 1..testNumber.toInt()) {
            calculation += "\nTest #$index = ${index * (testLevel + attempt)}"

Comment: This: val htmlText = "<body><br>$exportText</br></body>" does not work...

Comment: @AppMonster Of course that doesn't work, it needs a <br> for every linebreak (that's what br stands for). `exportText.lines().joinToString("\n") { HTML.escapeHtml(it) }`

Comment: exportText.lines().joinToString("\n") { Html.escapeHtml(it) } does not work... PDF output is still a one piece paragraph

Comment: @AppMonster Mistake, I meant to write `.joinToString("<br>")` but replaced the wrong part of my text.

Comment: still outputs full paragraph :(

Comment: I finally got it to work. You were right, I changed something and it finally worked. After 2 solid weeks of trying different things I retried this PDF generator and it worked. Thanks for the help:)